# Water Tank in loft no longer fills up

Tags: plumbing

When changing a washer on the kitchen tap we turned off the mains water supply from under the sink. However, when turning it back on we no longer have hot water in any taps and also no cold water in the shower or bath. Cold water in all sinks works fine.

Our system is gravity fed and it seems the tank in the loft is filling very slowely (only a drip).

Does anyone have any advice on what could be causing it and how to solve this?[image][image]

Comment: If it's gravity fed, how does the loft tank refill?

Comment: To be honest I’m not sure, my knowledge of plumbing is pretty limited. I know we have two tanks in the loft - one for radiators and one for hot water taps etc. The one for radiators seems ok but other is not filling up. Is there a way I can find out of loft tanks fill up?

Comment: Are you sure you turned on all of the values you turned off? Are they quarter-turn values (meaning they only turn a quarter turn, 90 degrees) or are they full turn (where you turn it multiple times until it tightens)?

Comment: We only turned one valve, which was the one below the sink. It needed a multiple turns, over one full turn to get the water off. Then it was turned a similar amount back again. The cold water runs as it did previously (there is really strong pressure in the kitchen tap).

Comment: You said "we turned off the mains water supply from under the sink". Is that the main cold water supply value for your home or just goes to the hot water valve on the sink?

Comment: It stops all water going into the house from the mains outside.

Comment: Please take a picture of your water tank and add it as a edit to your original post.

Comment: Hopefully those photos help, not easy to get good lighting + quality

Comment: We can't see anything useful from the pictures. Do you have a model number?

Comment: Fluid master side entry brass shank side entry fill valve 1/2”.  https://www.screwfix.com/p/fluidmaster-side-entry-fill-valve/85797

Answer (score 2):

It seems your fill valve is stuck in the off position.

I don't have that particular type of valve but I'd try wiggling the moving parts (the blue parts probably) to see if that frees things up.

The [instructions](http://www.free-instruction-manuals.com/pdf/pa_458221.pdf) show how to check the valve and replace the seals.

[image: diagram from user guide]

I'd turn main stopcock off, pull that valve cover off, clean all moving parts up and replace them.

If still not working , you may have to turn off the water and replace the seals with new parts or replace the whole valve with a new unit.

Comment: How strong should the flow be / how quickly should it fill back up? I am wondering because it feels strange that it worked perfectly before we turned mains off then nothing afterwards. I’ve moved the blue elements of the valve and nothing happens. Want to make sure this is the problem before messing with it!!

Comment: It should flow in about as fast as your kitchen sink cold tap. How long your tank takes to fill depends on how big it is of course. I've never timed it but I guess it might take 10-30 mins to refill from empty.

Comment: It should be roughly the same flow that you see at the kitchen sink. You lose a little pressure with the extra height but that should be negligible.

Comment: Ahh ok, definitely not flowing that well, a glorified trickle... I’ve been trying to research this and other forums suggest an airlock could be the problem for similar problems. Do you think this would explain what I’m seeing?

Comment: That is a possibility. I would drain the whole system - shut off the house main and open all of the taps, let all the water run out. Then turn on the house main and wait for water to start flowing, close the taps from the lowest part of the house first, work your way up to the top. That should force all the air to the top of the system. Maybe have a buddy up in the attic keep jiggling the cistern valve to make sure the air is getting pushed out. You don't have to do it at full pressure either - that can rattle things around quite a bit when it's going from totally empty to full.

Comment: Ok I’ll try that. Should the taps completely stop or should I expect drips?

Comment: I’ve just fully drained the system and did exactly as you said but still nothing going into the cistern. It might be worth saying some taps appear to be independent of the cistern and work fine. The others don’t let water out even when mains is turned back on (because cistern is empty I guess)

Comment: We have boiler that is used normally - that is turned off. Also the immersion back up is turned off

Comment: Having some colds work and others not is normal for this setup when the cistern is empty. The colds that are not flowing now should all be non-potable water sources - baths, showers, and hand washing sinks. Potable water should be attached directly to the mains without going through the cistern, so your kitchen cold should not be affected by an empty cistern.

Comment: Ok, good. So the condensation is probably just from the cistern walls being cold. I'll delete my other comments.

Comment: Ok great, it doesn’t seem like this has helped though unfortunately. Still only a drip filling the cistern. Any other ideas?

Comment: I would try taking the cistern valve off completely to test whether or not water is at least making it that far. Turn off the mains again (no need to drain anything this time) then unscrew the cistern valve, then have someone turn on the mains again just a little bit. Make sure they're within earshot so you can shout down to have them turn it off again once you've confirm water is reaching the attic. You may find that once all the air is out from behind the valve that it'll just work again after reattaching it, but if not then it looks like you'll need a new one.

Comment: If the test fails and no water reaches the cistern even with the valve removed then you have a problem somewhere else in the system. It's not uncommon for this setup to have a shutoff on the outside of the cistern. If yours has this, make sure that one is open too.

Comment: Ok I’ll give that a go tomorrow morning, fingers crossed! Thanks for all your advice, really appreciate it